# Как перевести Wifi адаптер в режим мониторинга?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

Можно ли перевести wifi адаптер TP-LINK в режим мониторинга? Через airmon-ng это не получается, потому что это не сетевой адаптер.

Comment: Смотря какой адаптер.

Comment: @DiD, 150M Wireless Lite N Router
Model No. TL-WR740N / TL-WR740ND

Comment: Вы можете попробовать поставить на роутер [dd-wrt](https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/?model=WR740N_1.x). Но c 32Мб оперативки он будет довольно туговато работать.

Comment: @DiD, а можно подробнее? Что такое dd-wrt и что с этим делать?

Comment: Ну а что вы хотите делать? Зачем вам режим монитора? Тем более на роутере с памятью прошивки 4mb, где нет даже usb-порта...

Comment: @DiD, handshake ловить.

Comment: И куда он их будет сохранять? Вам придется для этого писать прошивку.

Comment: @DiD, значит, все придется делать ручками?

Comment: А как это делать по-другому?